# How to Concurrently Process Lines of Text with RxJava

Tags: java, concurrency, reactive-programming, rx-java, observable

I was wondering how I could concurrently process lines of text with RxJava. Right now, what I have is an observable from an entry set, and a subscriber that on each entry, processes the entry in the onNext call. The subscriber subscribes to the observable with this line of code

```
obs.observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(sub);
```

But when I run it, it runs as slowly as the sequential version, and seems to be processing it sequentially. How would I make this concurrent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `observeOn(Schedulers.io())` call means that all emissions will be observed on that one thread. You want to get them onto their *own* threads.

Here I use `flatMap` to create a new observable for each item emitted from the source. Inside the mapping function I have to `defer` the processing work until subscription, else the entire chain is blocked while processing completes. I also have to ensure that subscription happens on a new thread via `subscribeOn`.

```
Random r = new Random();
Observable.from(new String[]{"First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth"})
    .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
        public Observable<String> call(final String s) {
            return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<String>>() {
                public Observable<String> call() {
                    Thread.sleep(r.nextInt(1000));
                    return Observable.just(s);
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
        }
    })
    .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(String s) {
            System.out.println("Observed " + s + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
    });
```

This gives me output like (note out-of-order and on different threads - ie, processed in parallel):

```
Observed Fourth on thread 17
Observed Second on thread 15
Observed Fifth on thread 18
Observed First on thread 14
Observed Third on thread 16
```

Comment: I would use Schedulers.computation() not Schedulers.newThread() so that a sensible sized pool of threads is used. subscribeOn is the key yep but watch out for the cost of context switching. Depending on the amount of time to process one line (I'm assuming it's pretty short) you may want to buffer lines (say .buffer(10000)) then flatMap onto Schedulers.computation.

Comment: How would I make this blocking? Not sure where to add the toBlocking() method; need to have it block while it processes so the main thread doesn't continue.

Comment: I just did `while(!subscription.isUnsubscribed()) { Thread.sleep(100); }` in my [test code](https://gist.github.com/adamsp/b136a8b40831dcb379b3). Probably not the best way to do that.

Comment: If you put some Thread.sleep in an action passed to subscribe(), you'll see that values are still being processed sequentially, instead of allocation a thread for each value. What you've deferred is a subscription, not the processing itself